# $meta: searchScoreDetails invalid and unsupported in mongodb realm text search

Tags: mongodb, realm, full-text-search

I am trying to implement a full text search service, where a user will type in the start of a name, and the service will return results matching the name (eg. I type in "Joh", the service returns "John", "Johnny", etc, from my mongo database), using the mongodb realm. Everything is good so far, except when I try to sort the results by score, I am using an aggregation pipeline, when I use the stage

```
{
    $addFields: {
        scoreDetails: { $meta: 'searchScoreDetails' },
    },
},
```

(straight from the documentation at https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/score/get-details/, It is supposed to add a field with the score and details of each document, that I can then sort.)
I get an error saying 'Location17308 Invalid $addFields :: caused by :: Unsupported argument to $meta: searchScoreDetails (status 500)'
When investigating, I stumbled upon something that said that the $meta operator is not supported by mongodb realm. Is anyone able to confirm what I read and/or give me ideas toward a solution ?

My $search stage looks like this :

```
{
    $search: {
        index: 'myIndex',
        queryString: {
            query: 'name:textToQuery',
            defaultPath: 'name',
    },
    scoreDetails: true,
    },
},
```

my index looks like this:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": true,
    "fields": {
      "name": {
        "analyzer": "customAnalyzer",
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  },
  "analyzers": [
    {
      "charFilters": [],
      "name": "customAnalyzer",
      "tokenFilters": [
        {
          "type": "lowercase"
        }
      ],
      "tokenizer": {
        "maxGram": 15,
        "minGram": 2,
        "type": "edgeGram"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Before answering, can you provide a bit more info as to what the expectation is of a - *full text search*? Also, there's nothing else in the question that references `searchScoreDetails` so can you also elaborate a bit on the usage? Please update and clarify the question so we can take a look.

Comment: I use the terms full text search, but I'm not 100% sure its appropriate to describe my use case, I left an explanation as to what I want to do with it.

Comment: Can you try adding a `$project` stage instead of the `$addFields stage`? I ran a quick test where after the `$search` stage I have `{ $project: { ..., scoreDetails: { $meta: "searchScoreDetails" }}}` and that seems to work just fine.

Comment: well I actually started with $project since it is what I found in the documentation, but addFields fits more my use case. Neither $project nor $addFields work, they both give me the same errors :(